# Java: resultSet update does not update database

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I am developing a Java app, as a learning tool for myself mainly, using a java database [tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/databases_and_java_forms.html), and for some reason, the resultSet update is not actually updating my database.

Details about the project: I am using the Netbeans IDE and connecting to a Derby database with 5 tables (each with between 3 and 6 columns). The database viewer window is supposed to load all of the records into resultSet's and set the text in each blank in the window to those stored records. This process and the buttons to move the cursor to First, Previous, Next, and Last all work perfectly. The part I am currently working on is making the Update button get the text in the blanks and update the records in the database, accordingly.

Now to the problem: the records don't update. When I run the project and change a value, then press Update, the value doesn't revert back to the original value or anything (since I'm not setting the text again in the updateButton method), but when I click next and then previous, the text is back to its original value. Additionally, the values are not updated when I close the application and query the records in the database. I also don't get any exceptions, and Netbeans tells me the build is successful.

Relevant code for the update method (and yes, I'm aware it's probably inefficient, but I'm trying to just get it working before I break it trying to make it look better):

```
private void btnUpdateRecordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        // get text from fields and convert to appropriate data type
        // in times
        String wakeTime = fieldWakeTime.getText();
        Time wakeTimeTm = java.sql.Time.valueOf(wakeTime);
        String outTime = fieldOutTime.getText();
        Time outTimeTm = java.sql.Time.valueOf(outTime);
        String inTime = fieldOutTime.getText();
        Time inTimeTm = java.sql.Time.valueOf(inTime);
        String sleepTime = fieldOutTime.getText();
        Time sleepTimeTm = java.sql.Time.valueOf(sleepTime);
        // in weights
        String morningPre = fieldPreWeight.getText();
        double morningPreDoub = Double.parseDouble(morningPre);
        String morningPost  = fieldPostWeight.getText();
        double morningPostDoub = Double.parseDouble(morningPost);
        String nightWeight = FieldNightWeight.getText();
        double nightWeightDoub = Double.parseDouble(nightWeight);
        // in meals
        String fullMeals = fieldFullMeals.getText();
        int fullMealsInt = Integer.parseInt(fullMeals);
        String snacks = fieldSnacks.getText();
        int snacksInt = Integer.parseInt(snacks);
        String sodas = fieldSodas.getText();
        int sodasInt = Integer.parseInt(sodas);
        String alcohol = fieldAlcohol.getText();
        double alcoholDoub = Double.parseDouble(alcohol);
        String desserts = fieldDesserts.getText();
        int dessertsInt = Integer.parseInt(desserts);
        // in ratings
        String morningMood = fieldMorningMood.getText();
        double morningMoodDoub = Double.parseDouble(morningMood);
        String nightMood = fieldNightMood.getText();
        double nightMoodDoub = Double.parseDouble(nightMood);
        String activityRating = fieldActivityRating.getText();
        double activityRatingDoub = Double.parseDouble(activityRating);

        // uses rs's to update db columns
        // in times
        rsTimes.updateTime("WAKE_TIME", wakeTimeTm);
        rsTimes.updateTime("OUT_TIME", outTimeTm);
        rsTimes.updateTime("IN_TIME", inTimeTm);
        rsTimes.updateTime("SLEEP_TIME", sleepTimeTm);
        // in weights
        rsWeights.updateDouble("MORNING_PRE", morningPreDoub);
        rsWeights.updateDouble("MORNING_POST", morningPostDoub);
        rsWeights.updateDouble("NIGHT_WEIGHT", nightWeightDoub);
        // in meals
        rsMeals.updateInt("FULL_MEALS", fullMealsInt);
        rsMeals.updateInt("SNACKS", snacksInt);
        rsMeals.updateInt("SODAS", sodasInt);
        rsMeals.updateDouble("ALCOHOL", alcoholDoub);
        rsMeals.updateInt("DESSERTS", dessertsInt);
        // in ratings
        rsRatings.updateDouble("MORNING_MOOD", morningMoodDoub);
        rsRatings.updateDouble("NIGHT_MOOD", nightMoodDoub);
        rsRatings.updateDouble("ACTIVITY_RATING", activityRatingDoub);

        // updates rows
        rsTimes.updateRow();
        rsRatings.updateRow();
        rsWeights.updateRow();
        rsMeals.updateRow();

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When searching out solutions to this problem I've come across a great deal of variations on suggestions to `con.setAutoCommit(false);` and then commit the changes at the end of the method block, which I have tried, as well as explicitly `con.setAutoCommit(true);` to see if it wasn't defaulting to that for some reason, neither of which worked. (For reference, I did an earlier version of this app using, following the tutorial much more closely and using just 1 of the resultSet's and 1 of my tables and was able to get the update button working.) Also, my prepared statements have the resultSet's set to `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, which I believe to be the correct options.

Link to the github repository of the project: [link](https://github.com/Grimmslaw/Metrika). The relevant file is MetrikaViewer.java, not DataManip.java, and the README (if you happened to need more information I didn't give you or like self-deprecating snark) is in the master branch, which is not where the rest of the code is (the Metrika branch) because of some problems I had using git (with an almost 100% chance of being caused by my own stupidity).

Really, as a still very new Java learner, I would not be at all surprised if this was caused by some weird misunderstanding of how something works on my part, but after a week of scratching my head, I just can't seem to find it.

Edit: As per Axel, I added updateRow's to the method. Now the changes update within the app while running, but it does not update the database. (I've updated the code above, accordingly, and the github repo should reflect the changes made.)

Answer (score 1):

I have never used these `updateXXX()` methods, but as I understand the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), you have to issue a call to either `rs.updateRow()` or `rs.insertRow()` after updating the columns.

Also, you have to make sure to create your statement with `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` (since by default, readonly is used).

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten about the updateRow call. Now the changes update within the running app, but do not update within the database. (I've edited the original post to reflect the changes.)

Comment: Now make sure to call `commit()` after the last call to `updateRow()` to make the changes persistent.

Comment: That definitely did it, thanks; I had forgotten to go back and add that `commit()` once I changed autoCommit back to false. Thanks a bunch. Out of curiosity, what is wrong with autoCommit? In researching the problem I was having, I saw a pretty large amount of people saying to always set it to false. What is its purpose if everyone seems to say to disable it?